# Alternatives for jcifs which is compatible with jdk 1.4

Tags: java, windows-7, jdk1.4, jcifs, windows-server-2008-r2

Are there any alternatives for jcifs which is compatible with jdk 1.4.
Alternatives for jcifs like waffle, jespa requires jdk 1.5

Our requirement is to authenticate from a Windows 7 (which sends only ntlm v2 responses) .net client using Windows 2008 R2 domain controllers.

Please don't suggest to upgrade to jdk 1.6 since we are using Jboss 3.2.0 and EJB 2.0.
Upgrading Jboss, EJB and making necessary changes in .net client - java server interaction takes time.

Thanks

Sajo C Mathew

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to upgrade JBoss.  Create a simple service in Java 6 which does what you want which can be accessed from your JBoss server.  You can't expect a simple solution to connecting a version of Java which EOLed before Windows 7 was even released.

BTW: Java 1.4 was EOLed two years ago, and asssuming Java 8 is released in 2012, Java 6 will start its EOL period then.  Don't wait too long. ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you upgrade to jdk6, you could still use jboss 3.2 and ejb 2 running on jdk6, don't you. I'm not aware of any (likely?) compability problems. Please advise, if I'm missing anything.

Another idea: Setup an iis in front of the jboss and let it handle the authentication.

btw: Even Java 5 was EOLed in 2009: http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5/